# Flutter: Scrollable Column child inside a fixed height Container

Tags: flutter, scroll, containers, height, fixed

I have several **containiers** inside a **ListView** which will result in a **scrollable content** within a page. **Each container has a Column as child** and within the Column I have a title and a divider, then the actual content.

---

I want one of the container to be something like:

```
Title
--------- (divider)
Scrollable content (most likely a ListView)
```

---

What I have so far:

```
Container(
    height: 250,
    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Text('Title'),
        Divider(),
        SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 15,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Text('abc');
                }
            )
        )
    ]
)
```

---

The thing is that I want the container to have a specific **height**, but I get an overflow pixel error.

[image]

Comment: try wrap listview.builder in Expanded

Comment: Thank you @MinhNguyên, that worked wonderful. I will set the Nbh's answer as the best answer just for others to see it more clearly and quickly, but you solved the problem. :)

Comment: can you give me  'useful' :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your `ListView` with `Expanded`. Remove your `SingleChildScrollView` as ListView has its own scrolling behaviour. Try as follows:

```
Container(
height: 250,
child: Column(children: <Widget>[
    Text('Title'),
    Divider(),
    Expanded(
      
        child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 15,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Text('abc');
            }
        ),
    
    )
]
))
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `ListView.builder()` widget inside a `SizedBox()` widget and specify available height after accommodating `Title()` widget.

```
Container(
    height: 250,
    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Text('Title'),
        Divider(),
        SizedBox(
            height: 200, // (250 - 50) where 50 units for other widgets
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 15,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Text('abc');
                    }
                )
            )
        )
    ]
)
```

You can also use `Container()` widget instead `SizedBox()` widget but only if needed.
`SizedBox()` is a const constructor where `Container()` widget is not, so `SizedBox()` allows the compiler to create more efficient code.