# How to stop listview from overflowing inside a column?

Tags: flutter, dart

So basically I ListView.builder widget inside of a fixed container.

```
          Container(
            height: 500,
            child: TabBarView(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 500,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: 100,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Center(child: Text("This is index $index"));
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Center(child: Text("Second Tab")),
                Center(child: Text("Third Tab")),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

**Issue:**

The issue with this widget is that since it is inside a container of a fixed height, the content of the list is cut off. I want the list to scroll along with the rest of the page so I don't want to remove the `shrinkWrap` nor `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`. I want it so that the list takes up as much room as it needs.

**Things I've tried:**

1. Wrap the ListView with a Column: this causes the widget to overflow and when I add the SingleChildScrollView around that Column, it removes the functionality of the `shrinkWrap` and `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`.
2. Checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67810792/flutter-scrollable-column-child-inside-a-fixed-height-container). **The parent widget is actually a CustomScrollView and this widget is inside of a SliverToBoxAdapter.** That's why the container has a fixed size in the first place.

What can I do to get the ListView to take up as much room as it want? Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but did you try out the `primary: false` inside the 'ListView'? The primary property makes the scrolling of the ListView stop and uses the scrolling from the parent.

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't work unfortunately. Thanks though.

Comment: If you want a Scrollable TabBarView, then I would recommend looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747149/how-to-create-a-bounded-scrollable-tabbarview. Probably changing your implementation a bit doesn't harm to make it look clean.

Comment: I actually ended up using a separate style but thank you! I just tried the solution from that post and it did work for my original use case. Annoying I couldn't find it earlier haha.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your container with `SingleChildScrollView` and make `scrollPhysics`

```
SingleChildScrollView(
           Container(
                  height: 500,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: 100,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Center(child: Text("This is index $index"));
                    },
                  ),
                ),
)
```

Comment: In `TabBar` dynamic height doesn't work, I tried it.

Comment: No when I do this, it removes the functionality of the ``shrinkWrap`` and ``NeverScrollableScrollPhysic()``. Basically I'm trying to get the instagram profile page functionality. Where everything scrolls together.

Comment: you want to scroll your tabbar also, am I right?

Comment: Yes make the children of the TabBarView scrollable. The problem is the fixed container but I have to keep it fixed because it is inside a SliverToBoxAdapter